# What are the objects and indirect objects in this sentence (if any)

Tags: syntactic-analysis, gerunds, complements

> The storage making your home work harder.

It's from a furniture advertisement, and I was just wondering how to dissect the complements here.
Is it that *storage* is the subject, *making* is the verb, *your home* is the indirect object (as it complements the verb *making*), and *work harder* is a direct object (as it is a gerund phrase?) Sorry if this seems a bit elementary to anyone - grammar is not my strong suit.

Comment: It's not a sentence. To diagram it, you'd have to expand it from marketing-ese to real English, so it'd have to be something like this: "This is the storage making your home work harder." I'm assuming it's above or below a picture of some storage solution. This happens frequently in ads where space is at a premium, and there aren't any hard and fast rules to how advertisers omit things.

Comment: Reads like a tag line: Ice...the cubes making your drinks clink! Potatoes...the eyes have it! Cat's captain's bed...the storage making your home work harder. All bets are off for grammar.

Comment: @FeliniusRex In which case, *This* would be the subject, *is making* the verb, *your home* the indirect object, and *work harder* the direct object? Again, sorry if this seems a silly thing to ask. And, yes, it was plastered above a hideous chest of drawers.

Comment: Well, if you want to go through the effort, then This = subject, is = verb, the storage = direct object, making your home work harder = adjective clause, describing *the storage*. This is an adjective clause because *making* is an adjective here.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Surely "the storage" is the subject complement, as the copula *be* doesn't take an object.

Answer (score 2):

The revised example sentence is

- *This is making your home work harder.*

There are two verbs (*make* and *work*), hence there are two clauses. Both have subjects, but only *make* has an object; *work* in the sense of 'expend energy' invoked by the adverb *harder* is intransitive.

The subject of *is making*, the main verb in the sentence, is *This*.
The subject of *work*, the verb in the infinitive clause, is *your home*.
The direct object of *is making* is the infinitive clause *(for) your home (to) work harder*.

The key question is whether *make* in this construction has an indirect object. Since indirect objects are invariably sentient, this should let out *your home* as the receiver. It certainly doesn't work with ordinary infinitive complements. Unless we're talking about AI, in which case we have personification.

- **I told your home to work harder.*
- **She ordered her car to go faster.*

But *make* is what linguists call a "small verb"; it's got a lot of individual peculiarities and has all kinds of idiomatic constructions it participates in. One sign of its small-verbness is the fact that not only is the *for* marking the subject of the infinitive deleted -- which is normal -- but the *to* marking the verb of the infinitive is also deleted -- which is not normal. Verbs like *make* that take *to*-less infinitives are special.

In particular, *make* can pass the tests for B-Equi if its indirect object is human. E.g,

- *We made her be examined by Dr. Jones.*

does **not** mean the same as

- *We made Dr. Jones examine her.*

But with a non-human NP, it appears to be B-Raising instead of B-Equi; in

- *She made it rain.*
- *He made the shit hit the fan.*

the dummy *it* and idiom *the shit* must originate in the infinitive, and they're metaphoric so they can't be the indirect object of *make*. And it fails the passive test

- *She made the truss be supported by the rafter.*

**does** mean the same as

- *She made the rafter support the truss.*

tl;dr - *make* is a very odd verb, and even small sentences with odd verbs can get complicated.